# PHP Conditional Tag

Tags: php, html

I'm trying to change the color of an SVG when the current page is "work.php"

Using the following code

```
<?php if($page=='work'){echo 'white';} else{echo '#C22533';}?>
```

I consistently get the color '#C22533' even if I am on "work.php"

How might I correct this PHP code?

Comment: Are you sure `$page` is actually equal to `work`? Eg, `var_dump($page)`

Comment: Please, show us `echo $page;` result

Comment: I am not proficient in PHP, I want to say

If page = work.php echo "white" if not echo "#C22533"

Comment: I think what people are asking is... how so you set the value of `$page`?

Comment: I haven't set the value of page, which leads me to believe this may be the error... How may I set the value of page?

Comment: Are you passing anything on parameters? What does $page do? I think you need to provide more info!!!

Comment: My page is written almost entirely in HTML. The only PHP code on the page is the one shown above.

Answer (score 2):

try this:

```
<?php
    echo (stripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], 'work.php')) ? 'white' : '#C22533';
?>
```

or, using your `$page` variable:

```
<?php
    $page = 'work';
    echo (stripos($_SERVER['PHP_SELF'], $page.'.php')) ? 'white' : '#C22533';
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

use

```
<?php
    if(pathinfo(__FILE__, PATHINFO_FILENAME) == 'work')
    {
        echo 'white';
    }
    else
    {
        echo '#C22533';
    }
?>
```